# How do I declare a new object within the same for loop without overwriting my previous iterations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, iterator

So my problem with this excercise is that after I have converted the first nested array into an object, the iteration will go into the next nested array and overwrite the first nested array I had just converted.

So one of my questions is how do I tell my code to stop iterating over what I just converted to an object and create a new object with the next nested array I need to convert?

Adding to my previous question, according to the exercise, I need to place my newly made objects and store them within an array. I planned on creating the objects first then pushing them into a placeholder array variable at the end. Is there a more efficient way to to this in the loop?

Any help would be appreciated, still kinda new here so dont be too mean haha.

Heres what Ive done so far + instructions!

*Write a function called “transformEmployeeData” that transforms some employee data from one format to another.

The argument will look like this:

```
[
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
]
Given that input, the return value should look like this:

[
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]
```

Note that the input may have a different number of rows or different keys than the given sample.

For example, let’s say the HR department adds a “tshirtSize” field to each employee record.
Your code should flexibly accommodate that. *

```
    function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
  debugger;
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < employeeData[i].length; y++) {
      obj[employeeData[i][y][0]] = employeeData[i][y][1]
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.map()` on the outer array and `.reduce()` on the inner.

```js
var data = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];

var res = data.map(a => a.reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({[k]: v, ...r}), {}));

console.log(res);
```

---

Or like this:

```js
var data = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];

var res = data.map(a => Object.assign({}, ...a.map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))));

console.log(res);
```

---

Or use actual `Map`s instead of objects. Then you can do this:

```js
var data = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];

var res = data.map(a => new Map(a));


for (const m of res) {
  for (const [k, v] of m) {
    console.log(k, v);
  }
  console.log("----------");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used your first suggestion as a template and worked backwards to solve it my way using 2 for loops.

But adding to the question (I hope you dont mind) if you take a look at my code which I used to solve the problem, why must I place a placeholder variable  under the first for loop for the code to work. I tried putting the undefined object variable near the top of my code but it wont work, why is that if you dont mind.

Comment: `function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  var arr = [];
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     // var obj = {};
    for (var y = 0; y < array[i].length; y++) {
      obj[array[i][y][0]] = array[i][y][1]
    }
    arr.push(obj)
  }
  return arr;
}`

Comment: It's because objects are a reference type, so if you only define it outside the loops, then inside you're always assigning to the *same* object. If you put it inside the loop, you're creating a new, unique object on every iteration